# Return struct based on largest field

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I have a list of structures. Each struct is a (make-struct STRING INT). I would like to go through the list recursively and return the structure with the largest INT field.

How can I do this? This has been one of the biggest coding challenge to me yet as a 24 month programmer. Fyi, I tried using a fold, I tried local variables(which gave errors), and built in functions, but nothing worked.

I need the logic...so depressing staring at my screen for 2 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with foldr is the base case (what do you do with an empty list?). This is a naive solution:

```
(foldr (lambda (x y)
         (if (> (struct-int x)
                (struct-int y))
             x
             y))
       (first list-of-structs)
       (rest  list-of-structs))
```

In this case, our "accumulator", y, keeps track of the struct with the largest int field. Each x is an x from your list. It compares the int in x with the int in y and keeps the largest struct.

Answer (score 2):

In Racket it's very easy to find a maximum using an arbitrary key, just use [`argmax`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._argmax%29%29) - this is the idiomatic solution, and should be preferred to using `foldl` or `foldr`. For example:

```
; replace `my-struct` `string` and `int` with the real names you're using
(struct my-struct (string int))

(define lst
  (list
   (my-struct "two" 2)
   (my-struct "three" 3)
   (my-struct "one" 1)))

; replace `my-struct-int` with the real accessor for the `int` field
(define the-max (argmax my-struct-int lst))
(my-struct-string the-max)
=> "three"
```

Comment: cool thanks for the contribution. This I hope that others can come here for the solution to what I consider a difficult problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a datatype `my-struct` with two fields, a string and an integer:

```
(struct my-struct (s i))
```

Now, let's make a list with instances of that new type:

```
(define slst `(,(my-struct "one" 1) ,(my-struct "two" 3) ,(my-struct "three" 2)))
```

Let's use a `foldl` to get the instance with the maximum value for the integer field:

```
(foldl (λ (s1 s2) (if (> (my-struct-i s1) (my-struct-i s2)) s1 s2))
       (car slst)
       (cdr slst)
 ))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for teaching me about fold. Its nice that I can move past this part in my program, but you people helped me understand that command. Thank you so much